# python httplib2 POST: how to set 'post parameter'?

Tags: python, post, urllib2

I'm getting an error posting xml to a site using urllib2.open with a urllib2 request. I set the data parameter as the xml string I need to post but the error I get is "the XML data was not sent in the POST parameter "xml".

Does anyone know how to set the data so it appears in a named 'post parameter'?

Thanks for any help

Code is like this:

```
req = urllib2.request(url=theurl,data = xml,headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml'}
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Where xml is just a string with the raw xml

If I print the req.data it gives the xml I want to post. But the receiving site wants that in a POST parameter called 'xml'. I have no idea how to control that.

Comment: Can you paste in the code that you have?

Comment: Use python-requests instead. Makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: There does not appear to be a `urllib2.open()` function: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html Do you mean `urllib2.urlopen()`?

Comment: yes sorry typo will edit

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be a dictionary of `'parameter_name': value`-type

```
url = 'http://www.someserver.com/some/handler'
values = {'name' : 'Some Name',
          'location' : 'SomeCity',
          'xml': your_xml}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```